# Php Session not working, with social login and normal php login

Tags: php, session

I have a problem with sessions for login in my website, 7phera.com/member_login.php, normal php session activating but when i login through social media it is only creating session for particular area, not for entire website session,

```
    <?php 
 $name = $_SESSION["userprofile"]['name'];
 $facebook_id = $_SESSION["userprofile"]['id'];
 $name =  $_SESSION["userprofile"]['name'];
 $uniqueID = "usr".StandardHash(microtime().$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
// $name .= " ";
 //$name .= $_SESSION["userprofile"]["last_name"];
 $gender = $_SESSION["userprofile"]['gender'];

$TodayDateTime = date("Y-m-d G:i:s");
$_REQUEST['registration_date'] = $TodayDateTime;
$_REQUEST['lastLogin'] = $TodayDateTime;
$today = date("Y-m-d");
 $oauthid_facebook = "facebook";
 include ('includes/config1.php');
  $facebook_id_query_check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_register WHERE facebook_id = $facebook_id"); 
 // $row_facebook_id_validate = Execute($facebook_id_query);
 $num_facebook_id_validate = mysql_num_rows($facebook_id_query_check);

if (empty($num_facebook_id_validate)) {

    $sql_facebook_id = "insert into tbl_register(uniqueID,registration_date,facebook_id,name,gender) values('$uniqueID','".$TodayDateTime."','".$facebook_id."','".$name."','".$gender."')";
mysql_query($sql_facebook_id);
 echo "Registered Successfully.".$assoc_facebook_id['facebook_id'];

 //$_SESSION['userid'] = $member['username'];
                            $_SESSION['id_user'] = $facebook_id;
                            //$_SESSION['id'] = $member['id'];
                            $_SESSION['member_unique_id']=$uniqueID;
                            //$_SESSION['member_name']=$member['name'];
                            $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
 //header('Location:http://7phera.com/my_profile.php');
    //echo "id already exists";
}else {
 $update_facebook_id = "UPDATE tbl_register SET name='$name', gender='$gender' where facebook_id='$fuid'";
 mysql_query($query);

//$_SESSION['id_user'] = true;
                            $_SESSION["userprofile"]['name'] = $name;

                            echo $_SESSION['name'];
                            //$_SESSION["userprofile"] = $uniqueID;
                            $LostLogin = date("Y-m-d G:i:s");                   
                            $res234 = Execute("update tbl_register set lastLogin = '$LostLogin' where facebook_id = '" . $_SESSION['id_user'] . "'");
 //header('Location:http://7phera.com/my_profile.php');
 //header("Location: ".$_SESSION['authstation']);

}
?>

    <!-- Start Welcome -->
    <div class="welcome">
    <?php
    $config[userinfo] =  $_SESSION["userprofile"]['name'] ;
    //session_register($_SESSION["userprofile"]);
     $_SESSION["userprofile"]['name'] = $name; ?>
        <h2>Hi, <?php echo $_SESSION["userprofile"]['name']; ?>, your email is  </h2>
        <p>You are logged in successfully. See your details below.</p>
    </div>
```

above session is working for particular area,please login through facebook once, I linked details in database when user login through facebook.

Comment: You should show the rest of the code... what is `$name`? How do you get it? is it set? etc etc etc

Comment: I have updated full code,  getting it from facebook.

Comment: You need to start the session with `session_start()` any time you want to use a session.

Comment: I added this code ` session_start();
header('Location:http://7phera.com/my_profile.php');`  but it is not registering session.

Comment: `session_start()` needs to be the very first line before you add anything. That means it has to be before you do your `$_SESSION[....] = ....`

Comment: can you login with facebook once? you will understand what my point is. http://7phera.com/register.php